# Correctly matching an ending tag with its starting tag in HTML with a RegEx

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, regex, asp.net-2.0

I'm using VB.Net in an ASP.Net 2.0 app to run some regular expressions that remove some unnecessary markup. One of the things that I'd like to do is remove span elements that don't have any attributes in them:

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, "<span\s*>(?<Text>.*?)</span>" & styleRegex, "${Text}", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

So for this content:

```
<span>Lorem <span class="special">ipsum</span> dolor sit amet.</span>
```

I'd like to remove the outer span elements. Unfortunately, my regex above gives me this as a result, since the closing span matches the first one it comes across:

```
Lorem <span class="special">ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
```

Is this possible with a RegEx or will I have to implement something a bit more advanced?

Comment: Since this is the (insert big number here)th iteration of the "Can I parse HTML with regex" topic, I'm posting this as a comment: Regex can't, by it's very definition, recognize nested structures. If you want to recognize a language (e.g. "nested structures"), by all means, use a parser. The behavior you see with your regex is as close as you will get with regex alone.

Comment: I would like to give as many upvotes to Tomalak's comment as the number of times this has come up in the last week alone.

Comment: So it sounds like the answer to my question is: No, yes.

Do any of the previously asked similar questions have answers with code for VB.Net/Asp.Net 2.0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516811/how-do-you-parse-an-html-in-vb-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916057/suggestion-needed-best-way-of-parsing-html-in-c, ..., http://www.google.com/search?q=html+parsing+.net+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Since only one of those mentioned Vb.Net, and none had any code specific to vb.net, I'll take that as a no. :-)

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to find some HTML parser for VB.NET and read the manual.

Comment: @travis: .NET is the key factor here. The rest is just syntax. Anything that works in C# works *exactly the same way* in VB.NET.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

Comment: Thanks @bemace, but that is most certainly not the case here, I just had a single wrapping SPAN from some malformed Word mark-up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT isn't an option since the input may not always be valid XML and the [HTML Agility Pack on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) looks pretty sweet but is really overkill in this case. Here's the final RegEx I ended up using:

```
<span\s*>(?<Text>.*?(?:<span[^>]*>.*?</span>.*?)*)</span>
```

Replacing that with `${Text}` effectively stripped the useless outer `span` tags in all cases I've tested.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly, regular expressions do not have this power. You'd need at least a context-sensitive language to express something like that. (sorry for the [theoretical stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy))

I'd also propose to use XSLT instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use XSLT rather than regex.

It seems .NET has good support for XSLT (google: xslt vb.net) but I don't know whether it will parse non-XHTML. The standard xsltproc command will, with the --html flag.

Answer (score 0):

HTML agility pack should help with this.

[HTML Agility Pack on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)