# i want to capture all tags not having a specific tag

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i want to capture all tags named 'STRONG' i can use `<STRONG.*?</STRONG>` this is working just fine but i dont want to capture these tags if the 'SPAN' tags come in these tags i want something like `<STRONG.*(^(SPAN)).*?</STRONG>`
this is the sample text

```
<STRONG> For technical <SPAN id=PageBreak>101</SPAN> please</STRONG>
<SPAN id=PageBreak type="4">56</SPAN><STRONG> visit</STRONG>
```

i want to capture the second strong tag and not the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Konrad is right.

But in case you don't care about imminent doom you could try something like

```
/<STRONG>\w+?<\/STRONG>/
```

Which will ignore STRONG tags if they enclose anything that isn't a word character, such as the `'<'` of `'<SPAN>'`, but will no doubt fail for anything out of the ordinary...leading back to the point about a doomed attempt.

Comment: "But in case you don't care about imminent doom" - well put! :D

Comment: i dont want only SPAN tags to be left out like you mentioned teh '<' if i want any other string to be missed how whould i cater that actually i want to leave out those strong tags which have a specific string plz help

Comment: That will work if every STRONG element happens to contain exactly one word. Obviously that's not the case.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to parse HTML structure using a regular expression, which is doomed to fail since the HTML language isn't regular (see [hierarchy of formal languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)).

Use an HTML parser instead, e.g. the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). See also [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916057/suggestion-needed-best-way-of-parsing-html-in-c).

Comment: no man...this is just an example...i m using a well formed html its not the part of the question weather its well formed or not u just supply with the answer....:P

Comment: shabby, no, even well formed HTML is not regular.  A regular expression is just a shorthand notation for creating a finite state automaton.  HTML cannot be parsed by a finite state automaton.  It's a mathematical fact.

Comment: Whether well-formed or not has absolutely no bearing on my answer. The only difference is that you can use an XML parser instead of an HTML parser if you use well-formed *XHTML* (or XML-style HTML5). Either way, regular expressions are unsuited for the task.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical use case for [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath). The query could be for example:

```
**/strong[not(child::span)]/text()
```

Comment: Very good answer. I atually wanted to post the XPath myself but I wasn't sure of the syntax (and now I see that I would have gotten it wrong).

Comment: @Konrad: Thanks @shabby: Good luck and may doom avoid you.

Comment: "No, I want to use a hammer, not a screwdriver."

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know in general how to match text that doesn't contain a certain sequence of characters, here's the most common way:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"<STRONG(?:(?!<SPAN).)*?</STRONG>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```